# How can I convert this query in pare.com query language for android?

Tags: android

```
SELECT  videoId, videoName, userId
FROM    dbo.tblVideo
WHERE   (userId IN
    (SELECT  toUserId
        FROM  dbo.tblFriends AS tblFriends_2
        WHERE  (fromUserId = '1') AND (requestStatus = 'f'))) OR
               (userId IN
                          (SELECT  fromUserId
                            FROM  dbo.tblFriends AS tblFriends_1
                            WHERE  (toUserId = '1') AND (requestStatus = 'f')));
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use rawQuery with this string?

```
String query = "SELECT  videoId, videoName, userId\n"
             + "FROM  dbo.tblVideo\n"
             + "WHERE  (userId IN\n"
             + "    (SELECT  toUserId\n"
             + "        FROM  dbo.tblFriends AS tblFriends_2\n"
             + "        WHERE  (fromUserId = ?) AND (requestStatus = ?))) OR\n"
             + "               (userId IN\n"
             + "               (SELECT  fromUserId\n"
             + "                   FROM  dbo.tblFriends AS tblFriends_1\n"
             + "                   WHERE  (toUserId = ?) AND (requestStatus = ?)));";

Cursor cursor = mySqlLiteDatabase.rawQuery(query, new String[]{"1","f","1","f"});
```

Comment: and minus what for? this is correct way (and only one) to get complex queries in android. If you have substantial point about the quality of the question than point it in a comment first, and don't be a troll here.